# can't create laravel 5.3 project using

Tags: laravel, newrelic, laravel-5.3

I get this error each time I'm trying to create laravel project

```
 Writing lock file
 Generating autoload files
 > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
 > php artisan optimize


[BadMethodCallException]      
Method after does not exist.  


Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

Comment: apparently this is related to new relic ... see https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/badmethodcallexception-with-message-method-after-does-not-exist?page=1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

The issue is causedby `newrelic`.

Try uninstall the newrelic agent for time being the error should disappear.